# Using XSLT to compare two XML files and generate a new XML file

Tags: xml, xslt, transform

I have two xml files, with the same structure, and I'd like to generate a new xml file with the same structure based on their contents.
For example:

File1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<coverage>
   <project timestamp="1369233123077" name="Project1">
      <metrics conditionals="664" methods="117" classes="13" files="9" coveredstatements="1554" />
   </project>
</coverage>
```

File2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<coverage>
   <project timestamp="1369224383368" name="Project1">
      <metrics conditionals="684" methods="122" classes="13" files="9" coveredstatements="1654" />
   </project>
</coverage>
```

The resulted file I hope to get, and it contains substractions of the identical attributes.
File3.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<coverage>
   <project timestamp1="1369233123077" timestamp2="1369224383368" name="Project1">
      <metrics conditionals="20" methods="5" classes="0" files="0" coveredstatements="100" />
   </project>
</coverage>
```

I tried XSL with File1.xml and managed to display the result as above, but I hoped to get a new XML file created on the hard drive.
Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say if the solution needs to handle more than one project or not, so I've assumed the answer is "yes, there could be multiple projects".  You also don't say if you can use XSLT 2.0 or are stuck with XSLT 1.0.

```
t:\ftemp>type file1.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<coverage>
   <project timestamp="1369233123077" name="Project1">
      <metrics conditionals="664" methods="117" classes="13" files="9" coveredstatements="1554" />
   </project>
</coverage>
t:\ftemp>type file2.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<coverage>
   <project timestamp="1369224383368" name="Project1">
      <metrics conditionals="684" methods="122" classes="13" files="9" coveredstatements="1654" />
   </project>
</coverage>
t:\ftemp>call xslt2 talleen.xsl talleen.xsl 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<coverage>
   <project timestamp1="1369224383368"
            timestamp2="1369233123077"
            name="Project1">
      <metrics conditionals="20"
               methods="5"
               classes="0"
               files="0"
               coveredstatements="100"/>
   </project>
</coverage>

t:\ftemp>type talleen.xsl 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="2.0">

<xsl:key name="projects" match="project" use="@name"/>
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="doc('file2.xml')/node()"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="project">
  <xsl:variable name="other" select="key('projects',@name,doc('file1.xml'))"/>
  <project timestamp1="{@timestamp}" timestamp2="{$other/@timestamp}"
           name="{@name}">
    <metrics>
      <xsl:for-each select="metrics/@*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{name(.)}"
                       select=". - $other/metrics/@*[name()=name(current())]"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </metrics>
  </project>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()"><!--identity for all other nodes-->
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
t:\ftemp>rem Done!
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Yes, it should handle a lot of projects. But each time, it only takes 2 files as input.
For the tools, I'm open to all possibilities.

Comment: Then my stylesheet should work for you:  it keys both input files on the name attribute of `<project>`.  I've just realized that in copying my result to my answer, I omitted the actual stylesheet that I used ... so that wasn't very much help to you at all!  Please forgive my oversight.  I'll now edit my answer to include the actual stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. My initial stylesheet worked, but I learned new stuffs from yours. I'm still stuck at the same obstacle. I'd like to execute one command, and get the file created. I tried Saxon with your stylesheet: `java -jar C:\Saxon\saxon9he.jar -o:result.xml -s:File1.xml -xsl:stylesheet.xsl` and I got this error message: `Error on line 29 column 16 of stylesheet.xsl: SXXP0003: Error reported by XML parser: XML document structures must start and  end within the same entity. Failed to compile stylesheet. 1 error detected.`. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: That error says that you've copied and pasted the solution incorrectly. You ought to be able to solve a simple XML well-formedness problem without help from StackOverflow.

Comment: You were right, a tag was missing. The command works even though I only gave File1.xml as a source. It also works if I gave File2.xml as a source. Is there a way I can pass both file names via command line without hardcoding them in the xsl file?

Comment: The stylesheet I gave you ignores the input file and accesses both files 1 and 2 by their file name.  If you look at the XSLT invocation in my transcript, you can see that I am using the stylesheet as both the input XML file and the stylesheet.  Just use global parameters to pass the file names from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

You're saying you've written the required XSLT code but you don't know how to save the result as a file on your hard disk?

That's then a question about the API of your chosen XSLT processor, so we need to know which XSLT processor you are using and how you are running it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I've only written a style-sheet file using XSL, and included it in File1.xml using this instruction:
`<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="style.xsl"?>`
Then I double click File1.xml to display it on the browser.
It's surely not the correct way.. and that's why I posted this question.

Comment: OK, then I misunderstood what you meant when you said you "managed to display the result as above".